# React router render component outside main component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm looking to render a SINGLE component at the root without rendering the extra components such as Nav.

This is my routes file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import Gatekeeper from './Gatekeeper';

import Home from './components/Pages/Home';
import StrainGrid from './components/Strains/StrainGrid';
import Single from './components/Strains/Single';
import Event from './components/Events/Event';
import Faqs from './components/Pages/Faqs';
import Login from './containers/Patients/Login';
import NewPatient from './containers/Patients/NewPatient';
import Billing from './containers/Patients/Billing';
import AdminDashboard from './containers/Admin/Dashboard';
import AdminAddEditUser from './containers/Admin/AddEditUser';
import PatientForm from './containers/Patients/Form';
import LandingPage from './components/Pages/LandingPage'

module.exports =(
    <Route path="/" component={Gatekeeper}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path='/view/:postId' component={Single}></Route>
        <Route path='/events/:eventId' component={Event}></Route>
        <Route path='/strainguide' component={StrainGrid}></Route>
        <Route path='/faqs' component={Faqs}></Route>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
        <Route path='/signup' component={NewPatient}></Route>
        <Route path='/patient/billing' component={Billing}></Route>
        <Route path='/admin' component={AdminDashboard}></Route>
        <Route path='/admin/addEdit' component={AdminAddEditUser}></Route>
        <Route path='/patient/form/:patientID' component={PatientForm}></Route>
        <Route path="*" component={Home} />
    </Route>
)
```

So I'm trying to render the "LandingPage" component as the IndexRoute, but of course get all the components that is being imported from the "Gatekeeper" component.

How can I make it so the index leads to the LandingPage component. But when you goto /app it will render the the GateKeeper component and all the imports etc...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nested routes? `<Route path="/" component={Gatekeeper}>` - `Gatekeeper` in this case uses like layout for a pages, including `LandingPage`.

You must add a second layer to routes, something like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={BlankLayout}>
    <IndexRoute component={LandingPage}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="*" component={Gatekeeper}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
    </Route>
</Route>
```